# Deeper TOC only in one section

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a deep title structure (until subsubsubsection) and want to show for the whole document only sections and subsections – this is easy so far. But for one section only, I want to have also subsubsections and subsubsubsections to appear in the TOC – is there any chance to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a simplified example, extending only to the subsection level.

the idea is to reset the reporting level in the `.toc` file itself.
this is done by inserting suitable commands with `\addtocontents` at appropriate points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\subsection{One-first}
text
\subsection{One-second}
text
\section{Second}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\subsection{Two-first}
text
\subsection{Two-second}
text
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\section{Third}
\subsection{Three-first}
text
\subsection{Three-second}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that it would be possible to pass that kind of argument to `\addtocontents`.